# Can I import variables from a .js file into package.json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, package.json

I have multiple `package.json` files that use the same set of values, so I would like to define these values as variables in a `.js` file, and share the file between the `package.json` files.

I am wondering if this is doable.

I see some tutorials teaching how to create variables inside a `package.json` file, but this way they cannot be accessed by other `package.json` files.

Is setting them as env variables the only way to do it?

Comment: JSON files don't have any import/require, so no.

Comment: If this is *really* needed, then it can be part of your CI/CD pipeline. Most CI tools would allow you to execute custom step before a build. And that step can be used to build up configuration for the build. Depending on the tool, it might even have a ready-made functionality for this - e.g., replace placeholders in templated files and you can define what the replacement is via rules (e.g., based on some tag, based on environment it's executed, or type of build, or whatever else). There might also be other pre-made config-building tools.